# Synchronised numpy 2D array counter with locks

Tags: synchronization, python-multiprocessing, numpy-ndarray

I want to parallelize a method that operates on a shared numpy 2D array.

My original application is part of a research and very complicated, however, I have created a toy example that essentially replicated the problems.

There is a clothing store that sells clothes of different sizes and colors. I represent the inventory of this store as a 2D matrix where `self.supply_arr[i][j]` represents a total availability of clothes of `size i` and `color j`. I have multiple customers attempting to purchase from the store. The store should not sell clothes more than its inventory. Below, I show a non-parallel example.

```py
import numpy as np


class ClothStore(object):
    def __init__(self, num_customers):
        self.supply_arr = np.random.randint(5, size=(2,2))
        self.sold_arr = np.zeros((2,2), dtype=int)
        self.num_customers = num_customers

    def make_purchase(self, size, color):
        left = self.supply_arr[size][color] - self.sold_arr[size][color]
        if left > 0:
            self.sold_arr[size][color] += 1
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def run(self):
        for customer in xrange(self.num_customers):
            size = np.random.randint(2)
            color = np.random.randint(2)

            purchase = self.make_purchase(size, color)

            if purchase:
                print "Customer: {} made successful purchase".format(customer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    store = ClothStore(100)
    store.run()

    print "Supply Arr: {}".format(store.supply_arr)
    print "Sold Arr: {}".format(store.sold_arr)
```

I have attempted to parallelize the `run(self)` method using `pathos` and representing `self.supply_arr` as `np.empty((2,2), dtype=object)` where each element I initialize as `multiprocessing.Value`. However, I have not been able to get it work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my own question using a roundabout way. It is not the most elegant way, but it works. I would really appreciate help in making it more elegant.

```py
import numpy as np
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
from multiprocess import Manager


class ClothStoreNew(object):
    def __init__(self, num_customers):
        self.supply_arr = np.random.randint(5, size=(2, 2))
        self.num_customers = num_customers

    def make_purchase(self, arg):
        sold_dict = arg[0]
        i = arg[1]

        size = self.demand[i][1]
        color = self.demand[i][2]
        sold = sold_dict.get((size, color), 0)
        if self.supply_arr[size][color] > sold:
            sold_dict[(size, color)] = sold + 1

    def run(self):
        m = Manager()
        sold_dict = m.dict()
        pool = Pool(processes=100)
        self.demand = []
        for customer in xrange(self.num_customers):
            size = np.random.randint(1)
            color = np.random.randint(1)
            self.demand.append([customer, size, color])

        pool.map(self.make_purchase, ([sold_dict, i] for i in xrange(self.num_customers)))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        return dict(sold_dict)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    store = ClothStoreNew(20)
    sold_dict = store.run()
    print "Supply Arr: {}".format(store.supply_arr)
    print "Sold Dict: {}".format(sold_dict)
```

As you can see, I am using `manager.dict()` for synchronization. I would like to use `manager.list()` but it does not seem to work. Moreover, using `Manager` locks down the entire dictionary for each update, an ideal solution would be one that locks each individual key of the dict (or each individual cell of a 2D matrix) at a time, so that processes operating on other cells do not have to wait.